# Android View Resources Inflation

Tags: java, android, xml, layout-inflater, aapt

I've gone through some docs and It basically tells that

- Although you see XML when writing your program, the Eclipse plug-in invokes the Android resource compiler, **aapt**, to **preprocess** the XML into a **compressed binary format**.**It is this format, not the original XML text, that is stored on the device
- For performance reasons, **view inflation** relies heavily on **pre-processing of XML files** that is done at build time. Therefore, it is not currently possible to use **LayoutInflater** with an XmlPullParser over a plain XML file at runtime; it only works with an **XmlPullParser** returned from a compiled resource (R.something file.)

Does the XML Layout goes as an argument to setContentView(R.something.file); **in binary format?**
When does the **Inflation** takes place?, Who implements **XmlPullParser** interface and when does it work in setContentView(R.something.file) method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does the XML Layout goes as an argument to setContentView(R.something.file); in binary format?

The XML layout file, like all resources written in XML format, is stored in the APK file in a "compressed binary format".

> When does the Inflation takes place?

In the case of layout XML resources, inflation takes place when somebody calls `inflate()` on a `LayoutInflater`. `setContentView()` uses a `LayoutInflater` to `inflate()` the layout XML resource you supply as a parameter.

> Who implements XmlPullParser interface

Whoever wants to.

> and when does it work?

Whenever anyone asks an instance of an implementation of the interface to work.

Comment: When i asked who implements XmlPullParser and when it work i meant during the inflation process of view hierarchy (maybe on setContentView(...) method) not in general.

Comment: @Tiko: [`XmlResourceParser`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/XmlResourceParser.html) is the implementation of the `XmlPullParser` interface used for parsing the "compressed binary format". `LayoutInflater` in turn uses `XmlResourceParser`, IIRC. Beyond that, I suggest looking at the source code.